# how to detect whether the function has run finished?

Tags: android, runnable

```
webservice.UpdateAllNews();
```

This function is downloading data from online database to local database.

What i want is i want to launch next activity after detect the function has downloaded finish all the data.

P/S the data is large

This is my current situation

```
webservice.UpdateAllNews();
                int secondsDelayed = 17;
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Main_Launcher.this,
                                Main_AllLatestNews.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }, secondsDelayed * 1000);
```

This is another class function

```
public void UpdateAllNews() {
    try {
        List<List_CategoryNews> newsCat = dbhelper.getAllNewsCategories();
        for (List_CategoryNews nwCat : newsCat) {

            int CatNewsID = nwCat.getCatID();

            if (CatNewsID != 0) {
                dbhelper.DeleteNews(CatNewsID);
                GetNews(CatNewsID, datetemp1, datetemp2);

            }

            String log = " NewsCatID- " + nwCat.getCatID()
                    + " category Name- " + nwCat.getNewCatName();
            System.out.println(log);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        b.setMessage(ex.toString());
        b.show();
    }
}
```

This one is constant launch after 17 seconds, i want auto start activity after finish downloading data from online database instead of delay 17 seconds.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the type of `webservice`? Can you please post the code for `UpdateAllNews()` method?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to use AsyncTask:

```
private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
    {
         webservice.UpdateAllNews();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
      startActivity(new Intent(Main_Launcher.this,Main_AllLatestNews.class));
      finish();
    }
}
```

and how to run it:

```
YourTask task = new YourTask();
task.execute("...");
```

Comment: this is class with asynchronic task, with will call some method after finish your method.

Comment: after i create this class, how to i call this class and how to run it?

Comment: i don't have any parameter to put inside as i want to run it once this activity is run and finish it to start next activity

Comment: you don't need any parameters to run this class. Just run it as I write above.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simple client-server methodology like Observer-Observable?
When the task is done the observable will call update function of the observer which will be your primary activity.

Comment: don't know what is that, so did not use